# Specifying the screen orientation of an ACTION_VIEW intent

Tags: android, android-intent, screen-orientation

I want to play a video, so I'm using action_view like this.

```
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

Does anyone know of a way to specify that I want the video always played in a vertical screen orientation, or that determination always up to an activity itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That determination is up to the activity itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the layout XML file you could add:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: ACTION_VIEW will get picked up by the appropriate viewers that the user has installed. One has no control over the layouts they use.